# Why is Bamboo throwing NoClassDefFoundError for embedded jetty tests?

Tags: maven, jetty, bamboo

We are running an embedded jetty server for integration testings inside the integration phase.

When we run the maven build locally it works fine, but on Bamboo it is failing with the following error:

```
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool$1
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.doStop(QueuedThreadPool.java:126)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStop(AggregateLifeCycle.java:107)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:69)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStop(HandlerWrapper.java:108)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:341)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ShutdownThread.run(ShutdownThread.java:131)
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34    Caused by: 
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$1
error   15-Oct-2015 16:03:34        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
```

We tried adding an explicit maven dependency to jetty-util for the missing class,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
</dependency>
```

but that did not work.

jetty-util is already included as a dependency and we see that it is correctly copied into WEB-INF/lib by default. Anyway, we also tried adding that jar to the web-app libraries, but that also did not work.

One very poignant observation... the missing class is QueuedThreadPool$1, an inner class of QueuedThreadPool. This is interesting because the call to QueuedThreadPool.doStop() is not failing until it, in turn calls QueuedThreadPool$1. But these are both defined in the same jar, so how can one be found and not the other? (I checked the dependency tree for the possibility that we were perhaps picking up an older version that did not contain that inner class, but that was not the case, and besides, all recent versions of the jar had the inner class anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having a similar issue i know this is from forever ago but di you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you reached `org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop` and `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop`, then there's no way for you to have a `ClassNotFoundException` for `QueuedThreadPool`, as that class was present from the beginning in order to even reach that point.

Something else is going on, this is not a ClassLoader issue, as you are assuming.

Comment: We are not getting a ClassNotFound, we are getting a NoClassDefFoundError, which is even harder to explain. In any case I would agree with your assessment were it not for the error message. One further complication is that this is not failing consistently. Once in a (very rare) while, it completes successfully on Bamboo, and when we run the build locally it always succeeds. That said, what else could it be???